# Netty client with synchronous request response

Tags: java, http, synchronization, httprequest, netty

i am trying to create a http client based on netty. I have written the code based on the [HttpSnoopClient example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClient.java) given in Netty site. But the problem is HttpResponse are handled by HttpSnoopClientHandler & HttpRequests are sent in HttpSnoopClient & i want to sync it. as in if i send a request i want to make sure that i will send the next request once i know the response to the previous. But since both are handled in different class, It is becoming difficult to do the same.

One thing i did was to create a setResponse() method in HttpTarget & HttpSnoopClientHandler will be setting the HttpResponse when it receives the Response from the sever. But i don't think it is a good approach since i won't be able to know the reposne was for which request.

So basically i want to do it synchronously i.e. send a request(channel.writeandFlush(req)) in HttpSnoopClient then wait till the response is received by the HttpSnoopCLientHandler & once it recieves a HTTP 1.1 200 OK then send the next request.

Can anyone tell me a good approach for doing it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT *(I've fixed it for you on this occasion.)*

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case where I had to block concurrent requests till one completes for a resource. I implemented a `ConcurrentHashMap<RequestKey, ArrayList<ChannelHandlerContext>>>` which will hold all the concurrent requests `ChannelHandlerContext` (ctx) and on completion of the first request raise an event which would trigger all other ctx to consume the cached response. In all this I had to make sure the `AUTO_READ` was set to `false` for fine grain control over the reads on each channel.

channelRead ->

```
if(map.contains(reqKey)){
    map.add(reqKey, list.add(ctx))
    //do nothing with AUTO_READ = false and do not initiate any ctx.* methods
}else{
    //firstRequest
    map.add(reqKey, new ArrayList<CTX>(){{ add(ctx);}})
    //continue with request execution
    //cache response and raise event on completion
}
```

userEventTriggered ->

```
onCompletionEvent {

    ctxList = map.get(reqKey).clone();
    map.remove(reqKey);
    for(blockedCtx : ctxList){
        //respond back with cached response to each blockedCtx
    }

}
```

@norman-maurer would you give your take on this !!!

Answer (score 0):

As you're creating a new HttpSnoopClientHandler for each connection, I would consider turning HttpSnoopClientHandler into a [ChannelDuplexHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelDuplexHandler.html). In the write method you can store a reference to the outgoing http request. When the response is received you can call your setResponse method with (channel, request, response). This should provide enough context so you can process the response correctly.

If your client is pure request/response, does not issue unrelated requests separately, and you want your application thread to process responses sequentially, then you could use a [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) to coordinate responses with allowing the main thread to continue. Alternatively your callback can process the responses internally.

You can also extends this technique to use HTTP pipelining. HTTP pipelining guarantees that responses are returned in the order that requests are issued. In HttpSnoopClientHandler you maintain a queue of requests. As each response is returned you match it to the request at the front of the queue.

Comment: wont the SynchronousQueue impl block the eventLoop ?

Comment: I didn't explain myself very well. I'm assuming that you want to process requests / response synchronously in your main thread, so your main thread sends the request then immediately asks (and blocks) for the response. The handover between the event loop and main thread would happen in the time it takes to perform the appropriate context switching. This might be sufficient, especially if you're not processing concurrent requests.